# how to ensure that sensors-detect didn't cause any damage

Tags: hardware, sensors, lm-sensors

I bought a Dell Inspiron 15 5501 (Intel Core i7-1065G7) last week and
installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10. I wanted to check if the
fan was working in Ubuntu and found out that one can use
sensors-detect for it.

I didn't read the warnings and gave "yes" for all the checks. Only
later I realised that it is recommended to avoid checks which are not
carried out by default. I am wondering if sensors-detect has caused
any damage in my machine. Can you please let me know if there is any systematic way
to check if there are any damages?

Comment: When you boot do you see any errors? You can check dmesg as well. What do you mean by damage?

Comment: @SimpliFixed, I don't see any errors when I boot. Thank you for the suggestion. I will check about dmesg.

Regarding the possible damage, the man page of sensors-detect says this: "...it can access chips in a way these chips do not like, causing problems ranging from SMBus lockup to permanent hardware damage (a rare case, thankfully.)"

Link: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sensors-detect